# Decrypting a file with CryptoStream but preventing writing a file

Tags: c#, file, encryption, aes

A while ago i started programming my own AES application to learn more about encryption. I managed to get the whole application working except for 1 thing that im still struggling with.

It is this scenario:
When a user wants to decrypt the files, the user has to enter a password to decrypt the files with. However, when the user enters the wrong password the decryption should fail. I know that when the CryptoStream throws a CryptoGraphicException it means that something went wrong, which in this case is decrypting with the wrong password. I will give a message like: "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed".

The problem is that when the user decrypts with the wrong password it still writes a new file that will containt the decrypted content. I really want to prevent that because it apparently alters the content of the encrypted file which renders it unable to be decrypted ever again.

My decryption code looks like this:

```
            using (AesManaged aesManaged = new AesManaged())
            {
            //Console.WriteLine("Decrypting file using " + aesManaged.Mode + ", block size " + aesManaged.BlockSize + " and padding mode " + aesManaged.Padding + "...");

            byte[] salt = GetSaltFromCiphertext(cipherText);
            byte[] initializationVector = GetInitializationVectorFromCiphertext(cipherText);
            byte[] fileContentToDecrypt = GetContentFromCiphertext(cipherText);

            //Initialize the AES instance with the key and the initialization vector
            aesManaged.Key = GenerateKey(password, salt);
            aesManaged.IV = initializationVector;

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("../../Files/" + fileNameAndExtension, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(fileContentToDecrypt, 0, fileContentToDecrypt.Length);
                }
            }
            }
```

How do i prevent the CryptoStream or FileStream from writing ANYTHING to the file when the user decrypts with the wrong password? Im generating an encryption key from the password using PBKDF2.

Comment: write to a temp file? write to memorystream?

Comment: I want to overwrite the encrypted file, with a decrypted file. It still does that, even though the password is wrong.

Comment: A cryptostream encripts when writes and decrypts when reads...

Comment: The cryptostream here decrypts it. You can see that i pass aesManager.CreateDecryptor().

Comment: Don't decrypt to FileStream, decrypt to MemoryStream first and only write to file on successful decrypt.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for that, will post if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using a MemoryStream instead of a FileStream. This makes sure that it has not yet written anything to the filestream when an exception is thrown by the cryptostream. The ciphertext will be located in the memorystream and can be written to a file if the decryption went well.